# Is there a major difference between the two scipy Hilbert transforms?

Tags: python, scipy

I was looking for Hilbert transforms in the scipy package and I noticed there are two versions of the Hilbert transform--one in [`scipy.fftpack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.hilbert.html) and the other in [`scipy.signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html). I saw that they differ in the outputs being complex conjugates, but are there any other fundamental difference between the two Hilbert transforms I should be aware of before using one version or the other? Nothing particularly jumped out at me when I looked at the source-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the pages, scipy.signal.hilbert computes the analytic signal, *using the Hilbert transform*. Namely, the analytical signal,

```
x_a = x + i*y
```

where y is the hilbert transform. On the other hand, scipy.fftpack.hilbert is just the Hilbert transform. If you want the Hilbert transform, not the analytical signal, use scipy.fftpack.hilbert.

Comment: Fair enough. Though is there a practical difference between the imaginary part of scipy.signal.hilbert and scipy.fftpack.hilbert? (Up to a sign).

Comment: Specifically one uses `y_j = sqrt(-1)*sign(j) * x_j` and the other uses `y_j = (-1)*sqrt(-1)*sign(j) * x_j`